# How does the compose compiler use activity lifecycle states under the hood?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In `@Composable` functions we can use states and completely replace `liveData` with `mutableStates` which does not require any `lifecycleObserver` instances.

My question :-

> How are the `@Composable` functions make use of the lifecycle states of the activity under the hood ( like `onStart()` ...`onStop()`) so that it does not have any side-effects ?

(Some compiler generated code can also help which explains the process)

Answer (score 1):

This is a large topic but most of what is needed is provided by the runtime, specifically the `AndroidComposeView` which will create and dispose its composition in response to lifecycle events. This in, in conjunction with `RememberObserver` form the basic building blocks for handling what you would normally do in the `Activity` lifecycle events.

The compiler doesn't generate any special code for this. The tracking information generated for composition is sufficient for the runtime to track this.